# Transit hotel and visa at Istanbul

Tags: layovers, accommodation, istanbul

We have a 9:30 hour layover at Istanbul airport, traveling from SFA to Dhaka. Will we get a free hotel provided by Turkish Airlines? Do we need transit visa?

Comment: What passport do you have?

Answer (score 8):

Turkish Airlines will provide a complimentary hotel if:

- You are an economy class passenger and the transit is more than 10 hours.
- OR you are a business class passenger and the transit is more than 7 hours.
- However, if another shorter connection is available then you cannot avail this complimentary offer.

So if there is another flight going to your destination which has a shorter connection time than your booked flight then the airline won't provide a complimentary hotel. Yes, sometimes we do book the flight options with longer connections because they are cheaper etc.

[Do You Provide Accommodation Services at Transit Locations to Passengers Who Have Connecting Flights?](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/frequently-asked-questions/travel-information/special-service-requests)

---

For the visa requirements, you will have to check that yourself. In the event where a visa is not granted, Turkish Airlines assumes no responsibility for providing complimentary hotel accommodation.

And the rule about transit visa is that if you are going to exit the transit lounge of the airport then you would need a transit visa. You should have a look at the [e-visa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/) requirements.

---

Unfortunately, your transit time might not be enough for a complimentary hotel, **BUT** you may get a [free tour of Istanbul](http://www.istanbulinhours.com/how-to-apply). The requirements are:

- You must have an international transit through Istanbul with Turkish Airlines.
- The transit time must be at least 6 hours
- Again the visa is your responsibility.

You just go to the hotel desk in the international arrivals hall 30 minutes before a tour and apply for it. There are 5 tours operated 7 days of the week. Of course, the tour timings should be comfortably within your arrival (30mins before tour starts) and departure (1 hour after tour ends) times. The [timings](http://www.istanbulinhours.com/TourScheduleByTime.aspx) of the tours are 8.30am-11.00am, 9.00am-3.00pm, 9.00am-6.00pm, 12.00pm-6.00pm and 4.00pm-9.00pm

Comment: It says citizens of Bangladesh are exempt from the quoted passage.